# Creating a shortcut to a listing of a specific content type or a set of specific nodes

Tags: nodes, users

I want to create a shortcut that acts similar as when you click the "Content" link. But I want to be able to display only a specific content-type or probably a specific set of nodes.

Is this possible weather by coding or through a module?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with the Views module and some additional extensions.

The easiest way to do it is to install the [Administration Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/admin_views) module (and all of its dependencies). It provides administrative lists just like you get from Drupal core, except they're built using Views.

Once you have that installed, go to /admin/structure/views. Clone the "Administration: Nodes" view provided by Administration Views, change the node type filter to be fixed instead of exposed, change the system path setting (eg. /admin/content/my-node-type) and save it.

That should be all - let me know if I messed a step or if something is unclear.

Comment: It's weird. The Auto-Preview is showing the correct result, but when I view the URL itself `/admin/content/type` it still shows everything.

Comment: Hmm, strange. Did you properly save the view after the last change? Is the view enabled? Did you clear all caches?

Comment: Yes I did all that. I was able to create a workaround though by creating a new page instead of using the cloned page. I don't know if this made the difference but the cloned page uses `Display: System` while the page I created uses `Display: Page`

Answer (score 0):

The Views module will facilitate what you're asking. You want to create a page view of nodes, in a table format, filtered by the criteria you want (e.g. node type), and set with page path. Once you have page path, you can add a shortcut to that path.